# Need help inserting data to database using php,ajax,javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Recently, i take some template from the internet and trying to understand the code. 
But i got stuck when trying to insert data to the database and the error message wont show.
Im sorry for my bad English

This is my piece of, master_menu.php

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="first_name">Nama Menu</label>
<input type="text" id="first_name" placeholder="Contoh : Ayam Goreng" class="form-control"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="last_name">Harga Pokok</label>
                                                <input type="text" id="last_name" placeholder="Contoh : 15000" class="form-control"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="email">Harga Jual</label>
<input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Contoh : 15000" class="form-control"/>
</div>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addRecord()">Tambahkan Menu</button>
</div>
```

And this is my piece of, function_script_master.js

```
function addRecord() {
    // get values
    var first_name = $("#first_name").val();
    var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    // Add record
    $.post("ajax/addRecord.php", {
        first_name: first_name,
        last_name: last_name,
        email: email
    }, function (data, status) {
        // close the popup
        $("#add_new_record_modal").modal("hide");

        //reload
        readRecords();

        // clear fields from the popup
        $("#first_name").val("");
        $("#last_name").val("");
        $("#email").val("");
    });
}

// READ records
function readRecords() {
    $.get("ajax/readRecords.php", {}, function (data, status) {
        $(".records_content").html(data);
    });
}
```

And this is my piece of, addRecord.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name']) && isset($_POST['email'])){
        // include Database connection file 
        include("function_connection.php");
        alert('clcicked');
        // get values 
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO MENUS(NAMA_MENU, HARGA_POKOK, HARGA_JUAL, STATUS) VALUES('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', 'aktif')";
        if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
            alert("Registrasi Sukses!");
        } else {
            alert("Username Yang Anda Inginkan Sudah Terpakai");
        }
        $conn->close();
        echo "1 Record Added!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? What should happen and what is happening instead? Do you see any errors in your dev console or the network tab or your dev tools?

Comment: inside php code alert will not going to work.... and u can print mysql error
using echo mysql_error(); before close connection....and see if its printing some error

Comment: Replace alert with echo because alert is not support in php, its for JavaScript.

Comment: unfortunately, no error was showed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code hope this helps, i just replaced alert with echo.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name']) && isset($_POST['email'])){
        // include Database connection file 
        include("function_connection.php");

        // get values 
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO MENUS(NAMA_MENU, HARGA_POKOK, HARGA_JUAL, STATUS) VALUES('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', 'aktif')";
        if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
            echo "Registrasi Sukses!";
        } else {
            echo "Username Yang Anda Inginkan Sudah Terpakai";
        }
        $conn->close();
        echo "1 Record Added!";
    }
?>
```